# Is there a way to redirect to a payment gateway via flutter with some data?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-html

I am using JazzCash Platform for online payment in Pakistan, All I need to do is make a Map<String,String> and redirect user to Jazzcash's website with the Map.

I checked out Url_Launcher (https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) and WebView For Flutter (https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) but both of them are not accepting body as their parameter.

Is there a way to do this in Flutter?

Here is the link for doing it Natively On Android : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MsBB80UBxeU

My Map:

```
var temp = {
        "pp_Amount": "1599",
        "pp_BillReference": "billRef",
        "pp_CustomerEmail": user.email,
        "pp_CustomerID": user.userId,
        "pp_CustomerMobile": user.phoneNumber,
        "pp_Description": "Description of transaction",
        "pp_IsRegisteredCustomer": "Yes",
        "pp_Language": "EN",
        "pp_MerchantID": "######",
        "pp_Password": "######",
        "pp_ReturnURL": "http//localhost/case.php",
        "pp_TxnCurrency": "PKR",
        "pp_TxnDateTime": currentDate,
        "pp_TxnExpiryDateTime": expDate,
        "pp_TxnRefNo": refNo,
        "pp_TxnType": "MPAY",
        "pp_Version": "2.0",
        "ppmpf_1": "1",
        "ppmpf_2": "2",
        "ppmpf_3": "3",
        "ppmpf_4": "4",
        "ppmpf_5": "5",
      };
```

URL Launcher Code, I tried sending the data in header, did not worked there either:

```
Future<void> _launchInBrowser(
        String url, Map<String, String> header1) async {
      print('In Launch Func: $header1');
      if (await canLaunch(url)) {
        await launch(
          url,
          forceSafariVC: false,
          forceWebView: false,
          headers: header1, 
        );
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch $url';
      }
    }
```

It works perfectly fine when I do http.post request but I need it to be redirected in the browser..

Answer (score 1):

This is something not meant for url_launcher or webview to do. On native android, a mobile SDK for the payment gateway is used.

What you need is a flutter plugin/package for this payment gateway. Head on to [pub.dev](https://pub.dev) to see if there is a plugin/package available. In the absence of non, you could consider building a plugin off the mobile SDK.